# Disable and re-enable user input without leaving textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on a small personal project that requires me to be able to enable and disable text input in a textarea through key commands. It will function similar to the way Vi/Vim handle insertion and command mode.

I cannot seem to figure out an elegant way to perform this task. Setting the textarea to disabled means that the user can no longer move their cursor caret through the text. Setting the keydown event to `return false` works for disabling the field, but obviously cannot re-enable it because it will instantly return false before reaching any other logic.

If there is any logic prior to the `return false` then the textarea takes the character input. I had attempted a version which accepts this input and instantly reverts it if it's not set to insertion mode, but this feels clunky and caused more problems than it was worth (plus it's not really instant...)

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle of this, just a simple demo, hitting d disables the field and hitting e enables it.  Other characters can be entered while enabled.  http://jsfiddle.net/gKDDh/1/

Try this, set a hidden field that contains the same text as the textarea.  Now never actually disable the textarea, just maybe change the background color or text color so the user can differentiate between disabled and not.  Then setup your logic like this.

```
onkeydown {
  if (state == disabled and hidden field value <> textarea value) {
    copy value from hidden field to textarea
  }
  else if (state == enabled) {
    copy value from textarea to hidden field
  }
```

basically what we are doing is keeping constant track of what the value should be, and only allowing a change when the state is enabled.

Comment: That sounds like it should work, although it may get a little slow if it's working with an extremely large chunk of text (since it's essentially duplicated). I'll give it a shot and update later.

Comment: true, but I'm sure it can be optimized.  I made a fiddle if you want to take a look.  You'll have to find a more elegant solution that using d and e because obviously it's hard to spell without those letters but the concept works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Vi/Vim but I think you are trying to achieve something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/FSjTa/

```
$('#text').keydown(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('command-mode')) {
        return false;            
    }
});
$('#btn-toggle').click(function() {
    $text = $('#text');
    if ($text.hasClass('input-mode')) {
        $text.removeClass('input-mode');
        $text.addClass('command-mode');
        $(this).html('command mode');
    } else {
        $text.removeClass('command-mode');
        $text.addClass('input-mode');
        $(this).html('input mode');
    }
});
```

I think the code should explain itself. If not, feel free to ask!

Comment: +1 This seems like a good approach. As an extension, you could still allow the arrow-key-down events to fire completely so that you can still navigate through the text.

Comment: This is similar to my current approach, but my issue lays in the fact that other keys aside from arrows will need to perform cursor movement. I could make exceptions for the non-character keys because they do not actually insert anything. Characters such as a-zA-Z1-0, etc will all insert in to the textarea prior to their exception logic.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery:

```
var txt = $("#txt");
txt.on("keyup",function(e){
  //Hit shift to disable
  if (e.keyCode === 16){
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
  } 
}); 

$("body").on("keyup",function(e){
  //Hit enter to enable
  if (e.keyCode === 13){
    txt.removeAttr("disabled","");
  } 
});
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/JMyTY/1/

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that the user can no longer move the caret around the text while the textarea is disabled.